# Updating a dictionary with functions

Tags: python, dictionary

So I'm having trouble with updating dictionaries in python. Here is the function with the dictionary:

```
def customer_dictionary(balfilename):
    d = {}
    bafile = open(balfilename, 'r')
    for line in bafile:
        dic = line.split()
        d[dic[1]] = [dic[0] , dic[2]]
    return d 
    bafile.close()
```

Now what I want to do is create another function which looks like:

```
def update_customer_dictionary(cdictionary, transfilename):
    transfile = open(transfilename. 'r')
    for line in transfile:
        act, trans = line.strip().split()
        if act in dictionary:
            cdictionary[act][1] += float(trans)
        else:
            cdictionary[act][2] = [act][2]
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to update the dictionary made in the previous function with this new function. cdictionary is the previous dictionary made.

```
File 1:
139-28-4313     115    1056.30
706-02-6945     135   -99.06
595-74-5767     143    4289.07
972-87-1379     155    3300.26
814-50-7178     162    3571.94
632-72-6766     182    3516.77
699-77-2796     191    2565.29

File 2:
380     2932.48
192     -830.84
379     2338.82
249     3444.99
466      -88.33
466     2702.32
502     -414.31
554      881.21
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how your dictionary is supposed to look like please? Also, please show your code for `update_customer_dictionary`

Comment: format your code as code so it is more readable please

Comment: Why not just pass the dictionary created by `customer_dictionary` as a parameter to `update_customer_dictionary`, and then return the changed dictionary?

Comment: how are you closing `bafile` AFTER the `return` statement?

Comment: The dictionary is suppose to look like this: {'115' : ['134-28-4313' , 1056.30]}. The code for update_customer_dictionary is what I don't know how to do. I'm not sure how to add file 2 to the exciting dictionary

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in `customer_dictionary` the line `bafile.close()` will never be executed since the function returns before that.  You should invert the order of the last two lines, or better yet, use a `with` context manager.

Secondly, when you read the balance file, you are leaving everything as a string.That's OK for the account and Social Security numbers, but you need to convert the balance to a float.

```
d[dic[1]] = [dic[0] , float(dic[2])]
```

As to you question about updating the dictionary, do something like

```
def update_customer_dictionary(cdictionary, transfilename):
    with open(transfilename) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            acct, trans = line.strip().split()
            try:
               cdictionary[acct][1] += float(trans)
            except KeyError:
               <Print appropriate error message>
```

I recommend looking at `collections.namedtuple.` If you define things appropriately, you can change `cdictionary[acct][1]` to the much clearer`cdictionary[acct].balance`.

Also, there is a potential round-off problem in using the floats I suggested above.  For a banking-type application, you might want to consider using the `decimal` module.

Comment: Is there a way without using try and except?

Comment: Yes, you can say `if acct in cdictionary` but `try ... except` is better.  Python will check if the key is in the dictionary whether or not you do, so doing the test explicitly adds nothing and just slows the program down.  If you're going to program in python, you really should get comfortable with `try ... except`.  But, of course, if you're just starting out, you don't have do so immediately. :-)